# Replace parts of string with objects

Tags: c#, string, split

I'm trying to convert parts of a string into different objects and join those into a list or array it doesn't matter.
Here's an example:

Sample string "This is a test string.\n \t This is a new line with a tab".

And i would like to get an output the one one bellow:

```
new List<OpenXmlElement>(){
                new Text("This is a test string."),
                new Break(),//this is for the \n char
                new TabChar(), //this is for the \t char
                new Text("This is a new line with a tab")
            };
```

I already have some the chars and the class types in a dictionary and i plan to instantiate them using reflection.

```
public static Dictionary<string, Type> Tags = new Dictionary<string, Type>()
    {
              {"\n",   typeof(Break)},
              {"\t",   typeof(TabChar)}
    };
```

I suppose i can doing using substrings or regex but i was hoping to find a cleaner solution.

Sorry if the question is not clear enough. I'll be glad to answer any questions you have

This is my full class

```
public class FormatConverter:IFormatConverter
{

    public static Dictionary<string, Type> Tags = new Dictionary<string, Type>()
    {
              {"\n",   typeof(Break)},
              {"\t",   typeof(TabChar)}
    };

    public IEnumerable<OpenXmlElement> Convert(string format)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string,Type> pair in Tags)
        {
            var items = format.Split(
                new []{pair.Key},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries
            );
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                yield return new Text(item);
                yield return Activator.CreateInstance(pair.Value) as OpenXmlElement;
            }
            format = format.Replace(pair.Key,"");
        }
    }
}
```

I know what's wrong with it just don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. In which part of the code you want help? Instantiating the Break and TabChar objects? 
As for the Dictionary with the <strings, Types> I do not see any problems with it, can't you just access it with the string value and get the type?

Comment: I know how to instantiate them but what i can't figure out is how to parse the string as to get the items in the correct order. And the dictionary is there just to show from where i get the data. Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you want to perform Lexical Analysis (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) on the text.

Comment: You need to parse the individual pieces from the first split when you do the second split.  You're splitting on the original text (minus the first key which you strip out) so you get duplicate entries in your output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that parses your sample text. It may not work so well in a real situation:

```
private readonly static Dictionary<char, Type> Tokens = new Dictionary<char, Type> { 
        { '\n', typeof(Break) },
        { '\t', typeof(TabChar) }
    };

private static IEnumerable<OpenXmlElement> Tokenize(string text)
{
    var start = 0;
    var pos = 0;

    foreach (var c in text)
    {
        Type tokenType;
        if (Tokens.TryGetValue(c, out tokenType))
        {
            if (pos > 0)
            {
                yield return new Text(text.Substring(start, pos));
            }
            yield return (OpenXmlElement)Activator.CreateInstance(tokenType);
            start += pos + 1;
            pos = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            pos++;
        }
    }

    if (pos > 0)
    {
        yield return new Text(text.Substring(start));
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var tokens = Tokenize("This is a test string.\n \t This is a new line with a tab").ToArray();

}
```

Comment: Had to change the line<br/> `yield return new Text(text.Substring(start, pos - start - 1));`<br/> to <br/>`yield return new Text(text.Substring(start, pos));` <br/> is there any reason u wrote it the way u did ?

Comment: @toby: yep, that was a pretty dumb mistake. It also missed the space between the newline and tab. I've update my example.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Split() method twice. The first time you Split on "\n" and then you could loop over the results inserting your Break object between each item.

You'd then run a split on all of the substrings for "\t" and loop again inserting Tab objects between items.

Not the most efficient since you're looping multiple times, but recursion should make the code pretty simple.

```
IEnumerable<OpenXmlElement> Convert(string testString) {

    IEnumerable<OpenXmlElement> tabOutput = ConvertString<TabChar>(testString, '\t');

    List<OpenXmlElement> finalOutput = new List<OpenXmlElement>();

    foreach(OpenXmlElement oxe in tabOutput){
        if (oxe is Text)
        {
            IEnumerable<OpenXmlElement> breakOutput = ConvertString<Break>(((Text)oxe).WrappedText, '\n');
            finalOutput.AddRange(breakOutput);
        }
        else
        {
            finalOutput.Add(oxe);
        }
    }
}

IEnumerable<OpenXmlElement> ConvertString<T>(string input, char pattern) 
where T: OpenXmlElement, new() {
    List<OpenXmlElement> output = new List<OpenXmlElement>();

    string[] parts = input.Split( pattern);

    if (parts.Length > 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
        {
            string part = parts[i];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(part))
            {
                output.Add(new Text(part));
            }
            if (i < (parts.Length - 1))
            {
                output.Add(new T());
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        output.Add(new Text(input));
    }

    return output;
}
```

Your other option would be to walk the string yourself manually and build your result as you go. It may not seem super elegant, but you'd do it in a single pass.

```
List<OpenXmlElement> output = new List<OpenXmlElement>();
string testString = "This is a test string.\n \t This is a new line with a tab";

System.Text.StringBuilder currentLine = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < testString.Length; i++) {
 char curChar = testString[i];

 bool clearCurrLine = true;
 OpenXmlElement objToAdd = null;

 switch (curChar)
 {
    case '\n':
      objToAdd = new Break();
      break;

    case '\t':
      objToAdd = new TabChar();
      break;

    default:
      currentLine.Append(curChar);
      clearCurrLine = false;
      break;
  }

  if (clearCurrLine)
  {
    output.Add(new Text(currentLine.ToString()));
    currentLine.Clear();
    output.Add(objToAdd);
  }
}
if (currentLine.Length > 0)
{
  output.Add(new Text(currentLine.ToString()));
}
```

Comment: I'm using the Split() method once for every item in the dictionary but the problem that the after the first pass, incorrect items area already added to my list the ones "\t".

Comment: I'm not at a computer right now, but when I get to one later I'll look at some code and see if I can help more.

Comment: I've put a couple of options up there that work.  Not necessarily the prettiest code (either of them) but see if they help.